# Serializing objects from projects written for different major versions of `System.Text.Json`

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, dependencies, system.text.json

My project, call it `Z`, depends on two other projects, `X`, and `Y`, and uses `Newtonsoft.Json` for its serialization, while also depending on `System.Text.Json 7.0.0` to provide annotation on its own types.

Project `X` depends on `System.Text.Json 7.0.0`. Project `Y` depends on `System.Text.Json 6.0.1`.

When using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` to serialize an object from `Y` I get the following exception:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=6.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).
```

This comes deep from `Newtonsoft.Json` trying to resolve attribute annotations on types in `Y` from some custom converter in it:

```
ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
CustomAttribute.IsCustomAttributeDefined(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Int32 attributeCtorToken, Boolean mustBeInheritable)
CustomAttribute.IsDefined(RuntimePropertyInfo property, RuntimeType caType)
DefaultContractResolver.GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
DefaultContractResolver.CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
<6 more frames...>
JToken.FromObjectInternal(Object o, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
JArray.FromObject(Object o, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
CustomConverterFromProjectY.WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeConvertable(JsonWriter writer, JsonConverter converter, Object value, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value)
```

My assumption is that it's because `Z` depends on version 7.0.0, so that one is loaded and doesn't work for 6.0.1. I tried downgrading `Z`' s dependency to 6.0.1, but then I get a symmetrical error when interacting with types from `X`:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Normally the resolution would be to make sure that `X` and `Y` use the same version of `System.Text.Json`, *but* here are two more caveats:

- **I do not control `X` or `Y` and cannot edit them.**
- There's a chance migrating from `Newtonsoft.Json` in `Z` to `System.Text.Json` would resolve the issue (since it's Newtonsoft's attribute lookup that throws the exception), but I want a solution without that. `Z` is a big project and a migration would cause significant cost and risk.

I need a way to use both `X` and `Y` without editing their dependencies. Is there a way to use two different versions of `System.Text.Json` in `Z` and have the reflection bits resolving attributes know where to find those? How can I resolve this?

All projects in question are built for .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Comment: If it matters, `Y` also supports .NET Standard 2.0, but `X` does not.

Comment: Have you tried using a [binding redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions)?

Comment: @V0ldek - You wrote *All projects in question are built for .NET Framework 4.6.2.* but System.Text.Json is only [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/overview#how-to-get-the-library) to work in .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later.  Though it does appear that NuGet states *.NET Framework 4.6.2 and later* so MSFT seems to have some inconsistency here.  Any chance that could be the problem?

Comment: @dbc I've never heard of it before. I'm going to read up, but if you could share an example of the configuration values for my scenario it could help a ton.

Comment: @V0ldek - sorry, not sure how to do it off the top of my head, and I don't have the appropriate tooling available right now to test it myself.  (That's why I made it a comment, not an answer.)  But I think it should be possible to redirect System.Text.Json version 6 to version 7.  You might need to redirect the dependencies also.

Comment: @dbc I filed an issue and got the docs fixed to correctly state .NET Framework 4.6.2 (https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/35113). Thanks for your help once again!

Answer (score 1):

@dbc's suggestion with [binding redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) is the solution here.

In `App.config` of project `Z` I added the following:

```xml
<configuration>
    ...
    <runtime>
        ...
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This should redirect all references to `System.Text.Json` to the newest version. This *kind of* worked – I started getting errors about different assemblies that were dependencies of `System.Text.Json`. I redirected all of them as well, and then the project worked. Here's the full config I had at the end:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.2" newVersion="4.0.1.2" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Additionally I had to put the same config in my test projects referencing `Z` for tests to pass.